# What Guna is our current Kalpa, the Sveta Varaha Kalpa?

Tags: puranas, kalpa

It is said in the Matysa Purana, that Brahma composes Puranas in accordance with the predominant Guna of that particular day of Brahma (Kalpa):

> ‘There are four categories — the mixed, the sattvik, the rajasik and the
>   tamasik'
>
> In the various Puranas produced in the past by Brahma,
>   deities have been praised corresponding to the dominant qualities of the epoch of
>   production.
>
> In the epochs of tamas the greatness of Agni and Shiva is praised. In the epochs
>   of rajas the greater greatness of Brahma is praised (Matsya. LIII, 68);’ ‘Then in the epochs
>   of sattva the still greater greatness of Hari is praised. Those who reach realization in them
>   attain the highest goal (Matsya. LIII, 67);’ ‘In the mixed epochs the greatness of Sarasvati
>   and manes is praised (Matsya. LIII, 69).’

And *Ramanujacharya* in his *[Vedartha Sangraha](http://www.srimatham.com/uploads/5/5/4/9/5549439/vedartha_sangraha_.pdf)*, or "Summary of the meaning of the Vedas," says:

> The idea of the foregoing is this: Brahma is the first individual self (in the realm of
>   samsara). Therefore even in him, some days sattva, some days rajas, and some days tamas
>   preponderate.
>
> Further, it is to be understood, that in case there is a conflict between the Puranas that have been composed by Brahma on the days in which sattva
>   preponderates and the Puranas that have been composed by him on other days, the Puranas
>   composed on the days of sattva are true and the others in conflict with them and composed
>   on other days are untrue. This principle of evaluation has been formulated by Brahma himself, when established in and devoted to sattva.
>
> The author of each of the Puranas, first of all gathered from Brahma himself all
>   the materials that should go into the particular Purana and then transmitted that body of
>   information through his composition. Accordingly it has been stated, ‘I will tell you, as
>   Brahma, told, in reply to the questions put to him by the great sages like Daksa (Vi. Pu.
>   1:2:8)’. (This is the governing principle of evaluation in connection with the Puranas).

Currently, we are in the [Shveta Varaha Kalpa](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/13635/why-is-present-kalpa-named-as-sweta-varaha-kalpa).

Does any scripture say what Guna this kalpa is?

Comment: Since Vishnu Purana (which is a Sattvika Purana) corresponds to Svetavaraha Kalpa, I think current Kalpa is Sattvika

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury How do you know it corresponds to this Kalpa?

Comment: You may be interested in my question https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32236/need-corresponding-sanskrit-verses-for-the-following-skanda-purana-verses

Comment: @Ikshvaku See this answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21446/is-each-of-the-18-mahapurans-related-to-a-different-kalpa/21448#21448

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury Oh ok, maybe you can answer this question then?

Comment: @Ikshvaku Okay, I might

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our current Kalpa, Svetavaraha Kalpa, is Sattvika. According to Chapter 53 of the Matsya Purana, the events of Svetavaraha Kalpa are described in the Vishnu Purana:

> Similarly, the rules of virtue laid down by 
>   Parashara, **for the period when there was the Varaha incarnation of Vishnu, in the beginning of Varaha Kalpa, form the Vishnu Purana**.

The same chapter describes that the Puranas which describe the glory of Vishnu are Sattvika in nature:

> **The glory of Hari is greater in Sattvika Puranas**; the glory of Brahma is greater in Rajasika Puranas; and that of Agni and Shiva greater in Tamasika Puranas. In mixed Puranas, the glory of Sarasvati and the pitrs is said to be greater.

Since Vishnu Purana describes the glories of Vishnu, logically the current Kalpa, Svetavaraha Kalpa, is Sattvika. This is in agreement with Skanda Purana too:

> **In the Sattvika Kalpas, the greatness of Hari is supreme**. They know that the greatness of Brahma reigns supreme in the Rajasa Kalpas.  (**Skanda Purana 7.1.2.87**)

Comment: yes,sattwik indeed:)